# Unable to launch Firefox browser using Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

Unable to launch Firefox browser using Selenium.

Below is the code that I executed:

```
public class BrowserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                           "D:\\Selenium\\BrowserJars\\geckodriver113.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line 
Host info: host: 'XXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:102)
    at BrowserTest.main(BrowserTest.java:12)
```

More details:

- Firefox Version: 113
- Gecko Driver Version: geckodriver-v0.33.0-win32 (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)|Build id: 20190614-1200

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the below line, you don't need to set property and provide the location of `driver.exe` if you are using Selenium `v4.6.0` or above.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                           "D:\\Selenium\\BrowserJars\\geckodriver113.exe");
```

References: [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)